# Show all the filenames present in the PWD and the directory at 3rd level

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint

**Without using find** and **Single command**: Show all the filenames present in the PWD and the directory at 3rd level.

I have a bad solution for show all files present at level 3 :

```
ls -l ./*/*/* |grep ^- |awk '{print $9}'| grep -E ^./\(.*/\){2}
```

or

```
ls -ld ./*/*/* |grep ^- |awk '{print $9}'
```

but how to extend this to show all files present in current directory and at level 3. I do not have to use find.

Comment: Can it get more homework-y than this? :)

Comment: Here is my answer after a little homework :

tree -fiF | grep -E -e '^./[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+$' -e '^./[[:alnum:]]+$'

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage a `for` construct with help from shell globbing and `test` (`[`):

```
for f in * */*/*; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f"; done
```

- `* */*/*` matches all files and directories in current directory (`*`) and third level (`*/*/*`)
- `[ -f "$f" ]` checks if it's a file, if so the filename is printed (`echo "$f"`)

Comment: Sorry I did not mention. I need to use single command. I tried your approach.
for entry in ./*/*/*; do   
if [[ -f "$entry" ]]
then
 echo "$entry" ; 
fi
done

Answer (score 0):

A perl version:

```
perl -E 'say for(grep {-f } <*>, <*/*/*>)'
```

or

```
perl -E 'map {say if -f} <*>, <*/*/*>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution : **Single command without find**

```
tree -fiF | grep -E -e '^./[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+/[[:alnum:]]+$' -e '^./[[:alnum:]]+$'
```